# ps: Get only COMMAND column

Tags: macos, xargs, ps

When I run `pgrep vim | xargs ps`, it prints

```
  PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
91234 s001  S+     0:03.14 vi user.py
93868 s005  S+     0:01.55 vi video.py
```

Yet when I run

```
pgrep vim | xargs ps -o command
```

it prints

```
COMMAND
-bash
tmux -2
-bash
vi user.py
-bash
-bash
vi video.py
(pgrep)
xargs ps -o command
-bash
-bash
-bash
-bash
-bash
sqlite3 spot.db
-bash
-bash
python app.py
/usr/bin/python app.py
-bash
/usr/bin/man lsof
sh -c (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 9.8i"; echo ".nr LL 9.8i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man8/lsof.8') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (/usr/bin/less -is || true))
sh -c (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 9.8i"; echo ".nr LL 9.8i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man8/lsof.8') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (/usr/bin/less -is || true))
/usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c
sh -c (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 9.8i"; echo ".nr LL 9.8i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man8/lsof.8') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | (/usr/bin/less -is || true))
/usr/bin/less -is
grotty
```

How can I print only

```
user.py
video.py
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pgrep vim | xargs ps | sed 1d | perl -lane 'print $F[5]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep vim | while read pid; do ps -p $pid -o command; done|grep -v "^COMMAND"
```